# Create list from boolean expression

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a column of boolean expressions and I want to make another column that is just a list of the elements of each expression.

EX

```
Name          Exp
 A     DDDD | LLLL & AAAA
 D     HHHH | DDDD | JJJJ
 O     UUUU & FFFF & RRRR
```

result df:

```
Name          Exp                   Exp List
 A     DDDD | LLLL & AAAA    ['DDDD','LLLL','AAAA']
 D     HHHH | DDDD | JJJJ    ['HHHH','DDDD','JJJJ']
 O     UUUU & FFFF & RRRR    ['UUUU','FFFF','RRRR']
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with regex `[a-zA-Z]+` for extract words:

```
df['Exp List'] = df['Exp'].str.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+')
#alternative
#df['Exp List'] = df['Exp'].str.findall(r'\w+')
print (df)
  Name                 Exp            Exp List
0    A  DDDD | LLLL & AAAA  [DDDD, LLLL, AAAA]
1    D  HHHH | DDDD | JJJJ  [HHHH, DDDD, JJJJ]
2    O  UUUU & FFFF & RRRR  [UUUU, FFFF, RRRR]
```

Solution with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with escaped separators with optional whitespaces is:

```
df['Exp List'] = df['Exp'].str.split(r'\s*\|\s*|\s*&\s*')
```

Comment: It will fail if the `Exp` column contains other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @jezrael will fail if the `Exp` column contains other special characters.

This implementation works if you know the boolean characters will always be either `|` or `&`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'D', 'O'],
                       'Exp': ['DDDD  | L-LL & AAAA', 'HHHH | DDDD | JJJJ', 'UUUU& FFFF & RRRR']})
>>> df

    Name    Exp
0   A       DDDD | L-LL & AAAA
1   D       HHHH | DDDD | JJJJ
2   O       UUUU & FFFF & RRRR

>>> df['Exp List'] = df['Exp'].str.split(r'\s*\||\s*&|\||\&')

>>> df

    Name    Exp                 Exp List
0   A       DDDD | L-LL & AAAA  [DDDD, L-LL, AAAA]
1   D       HHHH | DDDD | JJJJ  [HHHH, DDDD, JJJJ]
2   O       UUUU & FFFF & RRRR  [UUUU, FFFF, RRRR]
```

Comment: Thanks for that @jezrael, I have updated to work for spaces too.